# Wordpress showing 404 page template for unpublished posts

Tags: wordpress

When I open a URL that point to a post which is not published yet, wordpress shows a 404 page. But I want to show a meaningfull message to user that "your post is not published by admin, please contact admin to get it published"

How can I do this?

Edit: Is their any way i can get wordpress to run my single.php template instead of 404 template in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, just a hint add script kinda like this to `single.php`:

```
if($post['post_status'] == "publish"){
   //do something
}else {
   // it's not published (i.e. draft or other) so do nothing 
 }
```

just do  `print_r($post)` and it will show the full array with keys and values.

good luck !

Comment: but the problem is wordpress don't executes single.php but 404.php

Answer (score 0):

make url of the unpublished posts something like this. 
http://yoursite.com/?p=587&preview=true
And put charlie if else condition in single.php but remember user have to be logged in to see the preview of the post

Comment: thanks for coming with an option. But this will not work for me because I can't force user to logged in. Basically I would like wordpess to treat my published and unpublised posts same way.

Answer (score 0):

You can Show unpublished posts, instead of 404 page template by using the_posts filter.

For more information visit [this page](https://github.com/studio20nyu/Assignment-Desk/commit/b4c74701cb6538bf89cb341efc3692b59dbff43f#L0R29).